# Running /socket.io/socket.io.js using a public IP

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So, I'm trying to run my Node.js on my private server. Now the thing is, I've created a chat program, which works great and all when I run it on a local network.

Now, when I change the IP's to my public IP it won't load the `/socket.io/socket.io.js` file. It says `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

The parts of the code where I'm connecting are:

Server.js:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;
    console.log('info - socket.io started');

mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/chat', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
```

Index.html:

```
<script src="http://94.211.125.196:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
// Try connection
try {
    var socket = io.connect('http://94.211.125.196:8080');
} catch(e) {
    // Set status to warn user
}
</script>
```

I do have the required ports port forwarded to my server (`8080` & `27017`)

Comment: Does the database connection work? Mongo by default blocks everything except localhost (AFAIK).

Comment: Nope, I've changed that back to localhost as it will only run on the server anyways. @Dodekeract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not hosting the `socket.io.js` file. You need to include the js file from somewhere else or host it by starting a httpServer in your node script. Try using the socket.io cdn:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you by any chance also know how to fix the `var socket = io.connect('http://10.0.0.199:8080');` ?

Comment: What's wrong with that? If there's a socket server running at that address, it should connect. Do you have an error message?

Comment: I'd like that to have it public as well, but it does not connect when I change the private address to my public address.

Comment: Not sure from the information you've provided. Sounds like a routing or firewall issue if you can't access it publicly. Your code is sound.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that the port is open on the firewall and is port forwarded to the server. So I don't think that routing/firewall is the issue. Should I make a separate question about this?