# io.connect using a public IP not working - Node.js

Tags: node.js

So, I'm having an issue where I'm using a public IP in my `io.connect`. The problem is that it does not connect.

I'm 100% sure that the ports are opened and that the firewall is not blocking the ports.

The code is:

```
// Try connection
try {
    var socket = io.connect('http://94.211.125.196:8080');
} catch(e) {
    // Set status to warn user
}
```

I did not get any errors. It should only show some messages inside my chat program which it isn't because of the connection not working.

If I use a local IP it does work.

### UPDATE

I have asked a question about Node.js and public IP's before, which is different than this question because I was talking about the `/socket.io/socket.io.js` in that question. This question is about the `io.connect`.

Comment: try connecting to this address from telnet. does that work?

Comment: That port is closed. http://ismyportopen.com/

Comment: Are you sure your server is bound to that network address and not:  1) 127.0.0.1 or 2) some other Ethernet adapter or 3) an IPv6 address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running /socket.io/socket.io.js using a public IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370863/running-socket-io-socket-io-js-using-a-public-ip)

Comment: Yes, @MichaelBlankenship. I set up a static IP for that server and have port forwarded the `8080` port to that IP

Comment: Updated which an explanation @CarlK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue.

I check everything, I made sure that I port forwarded everything to correct way to the server and also made sure that the server wasn't blocking the port.

Apparently, my second router has all ports forwarded except this one. This caused the issue which is now fixed.

Thanks to everyone who helped!